# JSONB Array Output - Postgres 11.5

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSONB string in this format

```
{
    "RouteId": "90679754-89f5-48d7-99e1-5192bf0becf9",
    "Started": "2019-11-20T21:24:33.7294486Z",
    "RouteName": "ProcessRequestsAndPublishResponse",
    "MachineName": "5CG8134NJW-LA",
    "ChildProfiles": [
        {
            "ApiMethod": "ProcessApiRequest",
            "ExecuteType": null,
            "DurationMilliseconds": 2521.4,

        },
        {
            "ApiMethod": "PublishShipViaToQueue",
            "ExecuteType": null,
            "DurationMilliseconds": 0.6,
        }
    ],
    "DataBaseTimings": null,
    "DurationMilliseconds": 2522.6
}
```

How do I get the output in this format

```
| RouteName                             | Metrics               | Time    | TotalDuration   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ProcessRequestsAndPublishResponse     | ProcessApiRequest     | 2521.4  | 2522.6          |  
| ProcessRequestsAndPublishResponse     | PublishShipViaToQueue | 0.6     | 2522.6          |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help on this is appreciated

How do you also extend this in case there are different arrays. Sorry fairly new to the JSONB world.

```
{
    "RouteId": "af2e9cba-11ae-43a9-813c-d24ea574ee62",
    "RouteName": "GenerateRequestAndPublishToQueue",
    "ChildProfiles": [
        {
            "ApiMethod": "PublishShipViaRequestToQueue",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 0.1,
        }
    ],
    "DataBaseTimings": [
        {
            "ExecuteType": "OpenAsync",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 0.1
        },
        {
            "ExecuteType": "Reader",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 72.1
        },
        {
            "ExecuteType": "Close",
            "DurationMilliseconds": 15.9
        }
    ],
    "DurationMilliseconds": 88.6
}
```

The required output is something like this

```
| RouteName                             | Metrics                          | Time    | TotalDuration |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| GenerateRequestAndPublishToQueue      | PublishShipViaRequestToQueue     | 0.1     | 88.6          |  
| GenerateRequestAndPublishToQueue      | OpenAsync                        | 0.1     | 88.6          |  
| GenerateRequestAndPublishToQueue      | Reader                           | 72.1    | 88.6          |  
| GenerateRequestAndPublishToQueue      | Close                            | 15.9    | 88.6          |  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Side note: the trailing comma after the last key/value pair in the array elements make the json invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `lateral join` and use `jsonb_to_recordset()` to expand the inner json array as an inline table:

```
select
    js ->> 'RouteName' RouteName,
    xs."ApiMethod" Metrics,
    xs."DurationMilliseconds" "Time",
    js ->> 'DurationMilliseconds' TotalDuration
from t
cross join lateral jsonb_to_recordset( js -> 'ChildProfiles') 
    as xs("ApiMethod" text, "DurationMilliseconds" numeric)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=af3b20eab6852cb01d2a47c3227d5b04)**:

```
routename                         | metrics               |   Time | totalduration
:-------------------------------- | :-------------------- | -----: | :------------
ProcessRequestsAndPublishResponse | ProcessApiRequest     | 2521.4 | 2522.6       
ProcessRequestsAndPublishResponse | PublishShipViaToQueue |    0.6 | 2522.6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot on this. How would you modify if there  a different child array

Comment: @TheVMan: I am not sure what you mean. You just need to enumerate the keys that you want to grab in the child array element in the `as` clause of the `lateral join`. As long as the element has keys `ApiMethod` and `DurationMilliseconds`, this will work fine.

Comment: Updated the main question to give you an example of what I was referring too

Comment: @TheVMan: no the same query won't work for this. This is a different json structure, so it would require a different logic for parsing. But you have the general idea with my answer and Bergi's to handle that now.

Comment: @TheVMan you can combine results from the two different structures using `union all`. For example `with ... select ... from ... cross join ... union all select ... from ... cross join ...`.